# Promise.all() and then() issues

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Im having some issues with `Promise.all()`

Im trying to use this chain:

```
Promise.all([
    this.newContainerLoading,
    this.gsapAnim()
])
.then(
    Promise.all([
        this.fadeOut.bind(this),
        this.preload.bind(this)
    ])  
)
.then(this.fadeIn.bind(this))
```

But for some reason the 2 functions in the *second* `Promise.all()` are not even being called? Eg `fadeOut()` and `preload()` dont appear to be called at all, and the chain just skips to the final `then()` and does the `fadeIn()`

Any ideas as to what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bind` is used incorrectly here. The result of `.bind(this)` is bound function. It is not being called, unless it is called explicitly like `this.fadeOut.bind(this)()`.

The purpose of using `bind` with promises is to use bound functions as callbacks. `Promise.all` doesn't accept callbacks, but `then` does. And `Promise.all` returns a promise, so it has to be wrapped with arrow function. It should be:

```
Promise.all([
    this.newContainerLoading,
    this.gsapAnim()
])
.then(() => 
    Promise.all([
        this.fadeOut(),
        this.preload()
    ])  
)
.then(this.fadeIn.bind(this))
```

Comment: Thankyou! This was the answer.

The confusion came from the other `then()` calls that had `bind()` in them - but I see now that `bind()` returns a function, which is what `then()` is expecting, but `Promise.all()` wants an array of _promises_,  which I need to generate via _calling_ the functions `fadeOut` and `preload`, not _binding_ them. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Notice that you need to wrap second Promise.all with arrow function, because you need to have lexical `this` inside. This shouldn't be a problem since you're using ES6.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap `fadeOut` and `preload` in a function so they get called when `.all` resolved, otherwise they will be called immediately.

Below code shows one correct way to do it

```js
function newContainerLoading() {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('newContainerLoading');
      res()
    }, 1000)
   })
 }

function gsapAnim() {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('gsapAnim');
      res()
    }, 1000)
   }) 
}

function fadeOut() {
    return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('fadeOut');
      res()
    }, 1000)
   })
}

function preload() {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('preload');
      res()
    }, 1000)
   })  
}


function fadeIn() {
 console.log('fadeIn')
}


Promise.all([
    newContainerLoading(),
    gsapAnim()
])
.then(()=> 
    Promise.all([
        fadeOut(),
        preload()
    ])  
)
.then(fadeIn)
```

Comment: Can you explain why i need to wrap the second `Promise.all()` in a function like that?

Doesnt `Promise.all()` return a new single Promise object anyway? And also if the anonymous wrapper function in your example doesnt return the Promise, how will it know to when to do the next `then()`?

Comment: I just tested your example and it didnt work, same issue as before, the 2 functions in the second `Promise.all()` didnt get called

Comment: My main confusion was why the `preload()` and `fadeOut()` functions werent being called - but that was because I was using `bind()` in the `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the `then` section in the inner promise and use a variable to store the parent `this`, see following please:

```js
var self = this;

var newContainerLoading = "dummy";
function gsapAnim(){
  console.log("gsapAnim");
  return "gsapAnim";
}
function fadeOut(){
  console.log("fadeOut");
  return "fadeOut";
}
function preload(){
  console.log("preload");
  return "preload";
}
function fadeIn(){
  console.log("fadeIn");
  return "fadeIn";
}

Promise.all([
    this.newContainerLoading,
    this.gsapAnim()
])
.then(values => {
      Promise.all([
          self.fadeOut(),
          self.preload()
      ]).then(values => {console.log(values)})
   }
)
.then(self.fadeIn.bind(self))
```

If you want to keep the chain, you should call the last Promise when the first is completed, see following:

```js
var self = this;

var newContainerLoading = "dummy";
function gsapAnim(){
  console.log("gsapAnim");
  return "gsapAnim";
}
function fadeOut(){
  console.log("fadeOut");
  return "fadeOut";
}
function preload(){
  console.log("preload");
  return "preload";
}
function fadeIn(){
  console.log("fadeIn");
  return "fadeIn";
}

Promise.all([
    this.newContainerLoading,
    this.gsapAnim()
])
.then(values => {
      Promise.all([
          self.fadeOut(),
          self.preload()
      ]).then(self.fadeIn.bind(self))
   }
)
```

Comment: whats the `values` part for? do i need that? im not interested in values from the functions, i just want them to be called at the right time, and resolve the `Promise.all()` when they are done

Comment: also if i run your snippet, the "fadeIn" log is output _before_ the "fadeOut" and "preload" values log, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, every callback function (called in `then` methods) are asynchronous. So when the first then is computed, returns a new Promise that will be also asynchronous, so its executions starts immediately (may be before the end of the nested Promise). I hope it was clear.

Comment: Please, see my udpate, I've added a snippets where you can see how to execute another Promise in a sequential chaining.